# How to portably find local IPv4 _and_ IPv6 addresses using Python's stdlib?

Tags: python

I'm interested in enumerating *all* local ipv4 *and* ipv6 addresses on a system.

The solution needs to be pure python (without shelling out).

Ideally it's portable (Linux, OSX, Windows) but I doubt that's possible, so an answer for each platform would work, too...

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib but that only lists the first address, and only v4.  I need all of them, including v6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no portable way to do that.

On Linux, you may use [fcntl.ioctl](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl) with `op=SIOCGIFCONF` (which is defined as 0x8912).

If you're open to use a library, take a look at [netifaces](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/). It does exactly what you need, and supports Linux, Mac, Solaris, and Windows. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287065/298054) might give you and idea.